# Width of column for lyrics, songbook

Tags: overleaf, layout, column-width, songbook

I am trying to write a songbook for a friend of mine. But I am struggling to set the width of the column with lyrics (e.g. for Country Roads). I want one song on each page or in other words I want "Almost Heaven, West Virginia, Blue Ridge Mountains, Shenandoah River." in one line (see below)

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{Das kleine bunte Liederbuch}
\ohead[]{\today}
\cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
\setheadsepline[100mm]{0.3mm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{A book title}   
\author{Author Name} 
\date{\today} 


%=========================================
\begin{titlepage}
        \centering{
            {\fontsize{48}{48}\selectfont 
            Das kleine \vspace{3mm} bunte Liederbuch}
        }\\
            
        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering{\Large{\textit{Originalauflage: herausgegeben von Seppl}}}\\
        \vspace{\fill}
        \centering \large{2020}
\end{titlepage}


%=========================================
\newpage{}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{center}
    \Large{\parbox{10cm}{
        \begin{raggedright}
        {\Large 
            \textit{Sei Dir bewusst, dass Du der Andere bist.}
        }
    
        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---Earl Grey}
        \end{raggedright}
    }
\end{center}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
\noversenumbers

\songsection{Einführung}
\vspace{0.5cm}
Hier erklären wie das Buch aufgebaut ist.
\newpage

\songsection{Lagerfeuer}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Country roads}


\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Country roads (Capo 2nd)}[by={Bill Danoff, Taffy Nivert, and John Denver},
                     sr={Poems, Prayers and Promises},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\large{
\[G]Almost Heaven; \[Em]West Virginia,\[D]Blue Ridge Mountains, \[C]Shenandoah River.
}
\endverse

\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it loos currently]

Comment: Can you paste your code as one, single, compilable file so that we can see what's going on?   What you included has two `\begin{document}`s, and I am pretty sure near "Sei Dir bewusst, dass Du der Andere bist." there are some unmatched braces.

Comment: Have you read the manual fro the songs package?  That is the first thing anyone who helps you is going to do.

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior might be caused by songs module to use two column by default. You can change it using `\setcolumns{}` macro:

```
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\begin{document}

\songcolumns{1}

\begin{songs}{}
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

The whole page-width will be used for song's text/chords, and you avoid too early line breaking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
I think that your answer deserve to be more detailed.

Comment: You are talking about `\setcolumns` yet your example uses `\songcolumns`? Which one is it?